# jarsigner is not working on JDK 1.7

Tags: java, maven, ssl, jdk1.7, maven-jarsigner-plugin

We are using JDK 1.7 for our project, it was working fine till last week but now it is failing with below error,

**jarsigner: unable to sign jar: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake**

I came to know that this issue is due to the protocol used to communicate with time-stamp server, but I am not sure how to pass the parameter to jdk through pom.xml to enforce it to use TLSv1.2

**My Pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project.dews.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonPom</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>UserNameApplet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>User Name Applet</name>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
                        <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
                        <Codebase>*</Codebase>
                        <Caller-Allowable-Codebase>*</Caller-Allowable-Codebase>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                        <!--<goal>verify</goal>-->
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <keystore>src/main/keystore/keystore.ks</keystore>
                        <alias>85034585a-17b9-4a50-53e79d3a86345</alias>
                        <storepass>password</storepass>
                        <keypass>password</keypass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-tsa</argument>
                            <argument>https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
                        <!--<certs>true</certs>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Build Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jarsigner-plugin:1.4:sign (default) on project UserNameApplet: Failed executing 'cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\JAVA 7\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\..\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keystore src/main/keystore/keystore.ks -storepass ***** -tsa https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa -keypass ***** C:\2.X_Dev_Code_SVN\Project\Common\Applet\target\UserNameApplet-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 85034585a-17b9-4a50-53e79d3a86345"' - exitcode 1 -> 
        [INFO] jarsigner: unable to sign jar:    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

I tried disabling TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 from java control Panel as well as disabled it using jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
from java.security but I failed on both the cases and also for me I need to fix the issue only from the pom.xml.

Any suggestion to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: according to [this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604828/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh) you need to disable TLSv2.0